# SQL lite query for get the records in which current time range exist between range of time slots

Tags: mysql

The requirement  is to get the time slot from sql table with the help of current time .  Here is the table below   . The problem arises when i am trying to get the time slot that surpasses 24th hours  for example  like the Night shift . if my current time is 21:00 i am unable to get the time slot .
query made so far

```
SELECT 
  *,CURRENT_TIME
FROM
  tbl_shift 
WHERE CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN shift_start
  AND shift_end





shift_id  shift_name  shift_start  shift_end  
--------  ----------  -----------  -----------
       1  Morning     09:00:00     13:00:00   
       2  Evening    13:00:00      16:15:00   
       3  Night       16:01:00     09:00:00
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQLite? Tag accordingly please.

Comment: This sort of application is much easier to think about when you represent your time intervals (shifts) with start time and duration.

Comment: so lets assume  duration   6  hours and starting time is 19:00 so still the question remains same  .How would u sort it out can u elablorate